# Assigning to 'id<UITextFieldDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'HomeDataForm *const __strong'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I get the above warning message listed with the following code:

```
self.classNumberTF.delegate = self;
```

classNumberTF is a textField and a subview of a UIView of self. Self is of type NSObject (HomeDataForm). I use this line of code so that when the user taps "Done" on the keyboard, the keyboard is then dismissed. So it does what I intend, but I am not sure why I am getting the warning. I don't recall receiving this warning until after installing xcode 7. Thank you.

Comment: Dis you specify the delegate of the `textfield` in header file like `<UITextfiledDelegate>` ?

Comment: Just did it. Thank you that has resolved the warning.

Comment: No, do not add it to the header file. Add it to the class extension in the .m file. There's no reason to tell the world that you are the text field delegate.

Comment: rmaddy, can you please explain what the difference would be?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: added declaration  to HomeDataForm.m per rmaddy.

Original: Resolved with answer from Piyush Patel: added declaration  to HomeDataForm.h

Comment: This is the wrong solution. Add it to the class extension in the .m file, not to the public header file.

Comment: I adjusted it, but why should a declaration like that not be public? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: Because only things that other classes need to know about should be put in the public header file. Ask yourself this - do other classes need to know that this class is a text field delegate? Probably not.